# Update certificate in Outlook contacts

Tags: encryption, certificate, email

How can I update an encryption security in Outlook contacts?

I got an email signed with an updated certificate by someone who is already in my contacts with an expired certificate.

If I **REPLY** to that email, I can encrypt my reply and it works. However, if I try to make a new email to the same contact it does not work.

If I right-click on the From: field of the new email from the contact, and choose Add to Contacts, in other words try to create a brand new contact record (with the new certificate), it does not create a new Contact, it just brings up the old contact record with the old, expired certificate in it.

Comment: Have you try to remove old certificate? Have you try to install new certificate?

Comment: @RomeoNinov That was the key. I removed the old certificate. Then, when I re-added the contact, the certificate was updated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Tyler, do you want me to make it as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option to update the contact with the new certificate no longer exists in the newest Outlook version (2016/365). This was available for 2007/2010/2013.

You must delete the contact containing the old certificate, and then add the contact anew.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the sender's name, select the options button on the right of the popup, then add to your contacts.  Outlook will prompt you to add to existing contact, so just choose the contact you have already.  This will update any info that has changed, in this case the certificate.  I feel for you--this one took me a long time to figure out.

Comment: This does not work unless the old certificate is deleted first.

Comment: No?  That's how I got mine to update.  I wonder if it's different between Outlook versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013 it's a little convoluted.

First, export the new certificate from the email.  You do this by clicking on the certificate icon, click on `Details`, highlight bottom security layer and click `View Details`, click on `View Certificate`, change to the `Details` tab and click on `Copy to File`.  You can then run through the `Export Certificate` wizard.

Once that's done, close all those windows and open the contact in your Address Book.  Click on `Certificates` to view all the certificates presently attached to the contact.  On the right, click on `Import` and select the file you just created.

Once that's imported, you can highlight the new one and click on `Set as Default`.  If there's still an issue, you can `Remove` the old certificates, but that will remove your ability to verify old emails.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.msoutlook.info/question/727

Key Outlook 2013: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Contactcard

Key Outlook 2016:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Contactcard

Then add new DWORD-32 bit Value
Value name: turnonlegacygaldialog
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1

worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on a NMCI configuration of Office 2016:
Open email in its own window,
Right-click sender & pick Open Outlook Properties (which seems to be our Global Address List (GAL) version of contact card);
Click Add to Contacts (local Outlook card opens);
Click Save & Close;
"Duplicate Contact Card" dialog opens;
Click Update, then OK.
While trying prevous recomendations here, I had previously deleted the Cert for that contact, but maybe it will work if you don't (I did not want to use other option presented here to delete the entire contact, because I have added info not in our  GAL). Cheers!